# Deserializing dynamic JSON using JSON.Net deserializer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, elasticsearch, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to extend the JSON.net example given here 
Trying to follow JSON.net example from 
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/CustomCreationConverter.html to deserialize object.

Class Structure :

```
public class Rootobject
{
public int took { get; set; }
public bool timed_out { get; set; }
public _Shards _shards { get; set; }
public Hits hits { get; set; }
}

public class _Shards
{
public int total { get; set; }
public int successful { get; set; }
public int failed { get; set; }
}

public class Hits
{
public int total { get; set; }
public float max_score { get; set; }
public Hit[] hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hit
{
public string _index { get; set; }
public string _type { get; set; }
public string _id { get; set; }
public float _score { get; set; }
public Inner_Hits inner_hits { get; set; }
}

public class Inner_Hits
{
public Testp11 testp11 { get; set; }
public Testp10 testp10 { get; set; }
}

public class Testp11
{
public Hits1 hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hits1
{
public int total { get; set; }
public float max_score { get; set; }
public Hit1[] hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hit1
{
public string _index { get; set; }
public string _type { get; set; }
public string _id { get; set; }
public _Nested _nested { get; set; }
public float _score { get; set; }
public _Source _source { get; set; }
}

public class _Nested
{
public string field { get; set; }
public int offset { get; set; }
public _Nested1 _nested { get; set; }
}

public class _Nested1
{
public string field { get; set; }
public int offset { get; set; }
public _Nested2 _nested { get; set; }
}

public class _Nested2
{
public string field { get; set; }
public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class _Source
{
public string pname { get; set; }
public Value[] values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
public string pid { get; set; }
public string[] val { get; set; }
}

public class Testp10
{
public Hits2 hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hits2
{
public int total { get; set; }
public float max_score { get; set; }
public Hit2[] hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hit2
{
public string _index { get; set; }
public string _type { get; set; }
public string _id { get; set; }
public _Nested3 _nested { get; set; }
public float _score { get; set; }
public _Source1 _source { get; set; }
}

public class _Nested3
{
public string field { get; set; }
public int offset { get; set; }
public _Nested4 _nested { get; set; }
}

public class _Nested4
{
public string field { get; set; }
public int offset { get; set; }
public _Nested5 _nested { get; set; }
}

public class _Nested5
{
public string field { get; set; }
public int offset { get; set; }
}

public class _Source1
{
public string pname { get; set; }
public Value1[] values { get; set; }
}

public class Value1
{
public string pid { get; set; }
public string[] val { get; set; }
}
```

In my calling function for json doc :

```
  string json = "{  \"took\": 2,  \"timed_out\": false,  \"_shards\": {    \"total\": 5,    \"successful\": 5,    \"failed\": 0  },  \"hits\": {    \"total\": 4,    \"max_score\": 8.225408,    \"hits\": [      { \"_index\": \"dev28\", \"_type\": \"Index_Type1\", \"_id\": \"user_2\", \"_score\": 8.225408, \"inner_hits\": { \"testp11\": { \"hits\": {              \"total\": 1, \"max_score\": 5.816241, \"hits\": [ { \"_index\": \"dev28\",                  \"_type\": \"Index_Type1\",                  \"_id\": \"user_2\",                  \"_nested\": {  \"field\": \"doc\",\"offset\": 0, \"_nested\": { \"field\": \"roles\", \"offset\": 0, \"_nested\": { \"field\": \"permissions\", \"offset\": 0 } } }, \"_score\": 5.816241, \"_source\": { \"pname\": \"Permission1\", \"values\": [ { \"pid\": \"S1_P1\", \"val\": [ \"V12\", \"V11\" ] } ] } } ] } },\"testp10\": { \"hits\": { \"total\": 1, \"max_score\": 5.816241, \"hits\": [ { \"_index\": \"dev28\", \"_type\": \"Index_Type1\",\"_id\": \"user_2\", \"_nested\": { \"field\": \"doc\", \"offset\": 0, \"_nested\": {\"field\": \"roles\", \"offset\": 0, \"_nested\": { \"field\": \"permissions\", \"offset\": 0}} }, \"_score\": 5.816241, \"_source\": {\"pname\": \"Permission2\",\"values\": [ {\"pid\": \"S1_P1\", \"val\": [\"V12\",\"V11\" ]} ] } } ] } } } }]} }";            

            dynamic objResultElasticData = (Rootobject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Rootobject));
```

In above classes I have one of the class as "public class Inner_Hits" where-in data can be dynamic with different names. Currently it has "Testp11" & "Testp10", there can also be "Testp12" with same hierarchy as "Testp11", can someone give me a pointer how can i achieve this dynamic behavior.

Hoping someone can point me to correct direction.

Regards, 
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of Json.NET's ability to [serialize a dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) to a JSON name/value pair object to define your `inner_hits` as follows:

```
    public Dictionary<string, InnerHit> inner_hits { get; set; }
```

You should also combine the various duplicated classes created by your automatic code generator.  A full implementation would be:

```
public class Shards
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int successful { get; set; }
    public int failed { get; set; }
}

public class Nested
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)] // Do not write the null value
    public Nested _nested { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string pid { get; set; }
    public List<string> val { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public string pname { get; set; }
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }
}

public class Hit2
{
    public string _index { get; set; }
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public Nested _nested { get; set; }
    public double _score { get; set; }
    public Source _source { get; set; }
}

public class Hits2
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public double max_score { get; set; }
    public List<Hit2> hits { get; set; }
}

public class InnerHits
{
    public Hits2 hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hit
{
    public string _index { get; set; }
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public double _score { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, InnerHits> inner_hits { get; set; }
}

public class Hits
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public double max_score { get; set; }
    public List<Hit> hits { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int took { get; set; }
    public bool timed_out { get; set; }
    public Shards _shards { get; set; }
    public Hits hits { get; set; }
}
```

Also, there is no need to use `dynamic` here, you can just do:

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And gain the advantage of static checking for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

If your class properties are changing dynamically then, i think you can't use this parser. 
take a look at this. this may help you.
[DynamicJSon Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349646/Dynamic-JSON-parser)

Comment: Hi Harsh, verified java script parser link what you had provided, but if you check above answer provided by "dbc" that looks more clean. Thanks for your reply.